# Changing DataFrame columns and data based on logic

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis

So I have a pandas data frame consisting of data from boxing matches and their odds of winning. It's columns are:

```
[Red_fighter, Blue_fighter, Red_odds, Blue_odds, winner]
```

I want to change it so that if for example, blue's odds are 'less' than red's that blue gets added to column 'Favourite' and red gets added to 'Underdog' both of which replace 'Red_fighter' and 'Blue fighter'

```
[favourite, underdog, favourite_odds, underdog_odds, winner]
```

So if I have:

```
{'Red_fighter' : 'Tom Jones', 'Blue_fighter' : 'Jack Jackson', 'Red_odds' : 200, 'Blue_odds' : -200 , 'Winner' : 'Blue'}
```

It becomes:

```
{'Underdog' : 'Tom Jones', 'Favourite' : 'Jack Jackson', 'Red_odds' : 200, 'Blue_odds' : -200 , 'Winner' : 'Favourite'}
```

I appreciate any help you can give, I'm a newbie to pandas and data analytics in general, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this using the `pd.Series.where` method:

```py
df['Underdog'] = df.Red_fighter.where(df.Red_odds < df.Blue_odds, df.Blue_fighter)
df['Favourite'] = df.Red_fighter.where(df.Red_odds > df.Blue_odds, df.Blue_fighter)

df['Underdog_odds'] = df.Red_odds.where(df.Red_odds < df.Blue_odds, df.Blue_odds)
df['Favourite_odds'] = df.Red_odds.where(df.Red_odds > df.Blue_odds, df.Blue_odds)
```

This method works by replacing the values where a condition is **NOT** satisfied with values from another series. The remaining values which satisfy the condition are left untouched.

So for example if we have `df.A.where(cond, df.B)`, all rows where `cond` is `True` will have values from `A` and all rows where `cond` is `False` will have values from `B`. There is more information in [the documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html).

Comment: Also, would this make the 'Winner' column automatically have the data of 'Underdog' or 'Favourite' instead of Red or Blue?

Comment: No but you could make it in the same manner: `df.Winner = df.Red_fighter.where(df.Winner == 'Red', df.Blue_fighter)`. Also if the answer helped your question please mark it as accepted to conclude the thread :)